# Change Numbers on Android-Wheel?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

On Android-Wheel project at http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/ 
Blog at http://android-devblog.blogspot.com/2011/01/android-wheel-update-custom-views-for.html

**What/where should be changed so minutes (as example) on the time wheel, would show only numbers 00, 15, 30, 45 rather than all numbers 00 to 59 ?**

The author, Kankan said: "just use a custom adapter based on the numeric one, with predefined items."  But this is not enough lead to help me to change the project/code.

Can you provide specific lead on What/Where in the project should be changed ?

Answer (score 1):

I just thought if this helps someone they can try this approach. I created a sample class

public class NumericWheelAdapterV2 extends AbstractWheelTextAdapter {

```
protected NumericWheelAdapterV2(Context context) {
    super(context);

}

@Override
public int getItemsCount() {

    return 4;
}

@Override
protected CharSequence getItemText(int index) {
    if(0 == index){
        return "00";
    }else if(1 == index){
        return "15";
    } else if (2 == index){
        return "30";
    }else if (3 == index){
        return "45";
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

If you check out the project and poke around a bit you'll find "NumericWheelAdapter" to be a good starting point to look into.

The example does

```
@Override
    public CharSequence getItemText(int index) {
        if (index >= 0 && index < getItemsCount()) {
            int value = minValue + index;
            return format != null ? String.format(format, value) : Integer.toString(value);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

You could create your own NumericWheelAdapter that overrides CharSequence and instead of generating a value for each index, you can do something like index x 15 to get 0, 15, 30 ,45 and set min and max to 0 and 3.

I think you should be able to modify the code to your liking with these indications, otherwise  if after trial and error you can't, you can always come back for more help ^^

Cheers

Jason

Comment: Jason,
Thanks for your (amazingly) quick response. It seems you have used this project.
I update the method.
1) For simplicity let's assume: Minute wheel only and interval of 10, so numbers are 00, 10, ... 50
2) As example, for minute "03", the wheel should show (vertically) 40  50  00  10  20
3) Please note that the method:  getItemText()  is called from  class AbstractWheelTextAdapter  line 190.
4) Following code works for initial display. But doesn't work upon scrolling the wheel ?    
(on next comment post)

Comment: <pre>@Override
    public CharSequence getItemText(int index) {
     if (maxValue == 59){ 
      if(helpInd < -2)  // a class variable define as: private int helpInd = 2;
       helpInd = 2;
      index -= helpInd; 
      index /= 10;  
      index *= 10; 
      index += helpInd*10; 
      helpInd -= 1; 
      if(index < 0){
       index += 60; Log.d("Line", " NWA 83 Index: "+index);
      }
      return format != null ? String.format(format, index) : Integer.toString(index);
     } 
        return null;
    }<code>

Comment: Hi, I have never used this project, I just like trying out stuff and yesterday I had some time to kill. What you can do is edit your post to add the code that you tried (this will make it easier for others t follow what your doing). and put what you are actually get^^. I'll take a look during the day when I get some free time. cheers

Comment: Ok, I thought you know the project. It doesn't seem the method/code that you asked me to change, is the code/place to change ? So, I don't want to direct responder/s in a path that I'm not sure is the right one. If you get a chance to look at it and share your findings with me, would be great.